# extraneous key [KubernetesApiAccess] is not permitted - when running EKS Cloudformation

Tags: kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

When trying to create an EKS cluster using a 'well formed' cloud formation yaml template - i get the following CREATE_FAILED error in stacks event:

Properties validation failed for resource testCluster with message: #: extraneous key [KubernetesApiAccess] is not permitted

I was expecting it to run and create an EKS cluster

Comment: Have you already tried removing `KubernetesApiAccess` from the template?

Comment: Can you please paste CloudFormation template here? I think property **KubernetesApiAccess**  is not valid for EKS.

Comment: yes it seems KubernetesApiAccess is not permitted now (but it was previously), Anyway - i have removed it and works ok now. thanks